# Identify individual words within a string JAVA

Tags: java, string, variables, substring

My project has the user enter three words, all in one line, (of greater than two characters), Example: One Two Three, will chop some letters each word (see below for specifics), and finally combine the modified words into one big word.

I wrote it all out in pseudo code, but I'm having an issue finding out how to use the substring method to determine when one word ends, and the next one begins. What I think I could do is somehow identify the space between words, and make that the breaking point. Is there some kind of if statement I could use for that? Like "if (nextchar = ' ') start storing in the next variable? And fit that all in a while loop?

If I've made that too confusing, here's the assignment my professor gave me. Please don't just give me the answer, I would much rather be pointed in the right direction and figure it out.

1. Prompt the user to enter three words, separated by spaces. Input the words as Strings.
2. Concatenate together all the characters in the first word, except the first one, with all the characters in the second
   word, except the first and last ones with all the characters in the third word, except the last one. Print this String and
   only this String out. You may assume – for the sake of simplicity – that each word that the user enters has at least
   two characters (you do NOT have to check for this). For example, if the three words input are “fun”, “With”,
   “Strings”, then the output for this step should be “unitString”. Hint: use the substring() method for this step. Another
   hint: store the substrings in three new String variables, so you don’t end up changing the three original words.

Thanks!

Comment: Holy wall of text is back.

Comment: Try what you think will work with the substring method and then post any issues/errors you are having. You will do yourself a favor if you try what you think might work before posting for help.

Comment: The question could've been phrased better, but I really don't see the need to pile on a beginner (who is probably new to the community) and ultimately discourage him/her from becoming part of it. Gentle guidance on community norms, and on his/her problem, is preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to read the input:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Then these to read the three inputs from the user (entered one line after another):

```
first = s.nextLine();
second = s.nextLine();
third = s.nextLine();
```

Finally, to use [substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) as your professor described:

```
firstProcessed = first.substring(1, first.length - 1);
```

This gets the first input word and slices it from the second character to the second-to-last-character.

Hope you can take it the rest of the way.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm supposed to take the input in one line, not three. That's where my problem is coming from.

Comment: Then read a single line, and call line.split(" "). This will produce a three element array. You then process those strings as described above. Or as @Vae suggested, you can use StringTokenizer as well http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Answer (score 4):

Use [`myString.Split(" ");`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

The code to text ratio is awefully low. Please revise the [rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for future reference.

More to the [point](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions):

> Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Finally, follow this [checklist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) for your next questions. Otherwise you'll have a much worse reception should people notice this is recurring behaviour.

Comment: I understand the problem. I even explained it in my own words, in addition to posting my instructors explanation.

I searched around the site, but was having issues with keywords. I kept coming back to something called "split", but we haven't learned that yet so I didn't want to mess with it.

I included code snippets that I thought were relevant, but was having trouble putting them into practice.

Comment: Your entire career as a programmer will consist of 'messing with it'. Look up what it does in the official documentation and start trying, there's no better way to learn. Don't let the pace of the course hold you back either, there's nothing bad about having a head start.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the following: `String.substring()` commands or the `StringTokenizer` class.

`String.subString()` will allow you to break your input based on indeces. You could search for the indeces of white spaces and return substrings from between them.

`StringTokenizer` will allow you to break a String into tokens by delimiter, i.e. you could use " " as a delimiter and the tokenizer will separate the String into tokens between the whitespaces.